# Why does using itext xmlworker in java giving a strange error?

Tags: java, itext, wkhtmltopdf, xmlworker, xmlworkerhelper

i'm trying to get byte array of html string after convert this string to pdfwriter. When i run into `XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml`, it return weird error: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "100%"`.
I have searched a few places but to no avail, here my function

```
byte[] convertHtmlToPdfBytes( String htmlString ) {
    Document document = new Document();

    ByteArrayOutputStream outp = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outp);
    document.open();

    InputStream inp = IOUtils.toInputStream(htmlString);
    XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, inp);

    document.close();

    return outp.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: May be Something related to Input which it unable to parse  .

Comment: @AnandDwivedi i looking back at my Input, it's have some special character, do u have any ideal to fix this?

Comment: May be can you try with
XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, inp, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

Comment: Also per method naming convention looks like it should be valid XML or html

Comment: i dont thing my input html is invalid, i copy my string html and parse to file and it work. I try Charset.forName("UTF-8") like you said but nothing change